# How should a court case be mentioned in a Chicago Style Essay?

Tags: format

I'm currently writing an essay that mentions many cases that were heard by the Supreme Court. I know how to cite them, but when I mention them in-text how should I format them? For example, one case is Debs v. United States. Should that be italicized or placed in quotations marks? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Chicago Manual of Style* recommends that in general essays, the parties' names be set in italic.  The *v*-for-versus may be set in either roman or italic. Thus

> *Debs v. United States*
>   *Debs* v. *United States*
>   *Debs v. United States*, 249 U.S. 211 (1919)
>   *Debs* v. *United States*, 249 U.S. 211 (1919)

If your audience is the legal profession, *CMS* also accepts the standard of the *Harvard Law Review*'s *Uniform System of Citation*, which sets cases in roman:

> Debs v. United States, 249 U.S. 211 (1919)